# How to connect to salesforce instance

Tags: soap-api, integration, bulk-api, salesforce2salesforce

I am exploring some option to connect two Sales force Orgs. My requirement is the following:

1. Any update to a record in one org should update the records in another org. Both org has an object with same name - XYZ. The object has an external id based on which it can upsert the record
2. Need to update the lookup record on XYZ object. If there is any parent of XYZ then that needs to be updated as well.
3. If there is any failure in upsert then the destination system where upsert has happened should show what records upsert has failed. like the bulk data load job logs
4. The connection can be real time or batch processing ( async). Real time - as soon as the records gets updated in one instance it should reflect in another instance. Batch - A batch file can get all the updated records in a day and update it in different instance.
5. Does Salesforce to Salesforce (S2S) is of any use here? Since it is an in built feature of salesforce will it help in using this here? Does it show any logs of the records which are upserted? Will I be able to also update the lookup object record on XYZ object.
6. Making an rest api/ bulk api callout from 1 salesforce instance to another instance where I need to update/insert the records. Bulk Api will produce log files. Can I send the records in JSON format from one instance to another using API callout?

Any suggestions? What is my best and optimal option here?

Comment: S2S may be your best bet, but have you tried it yet?

Comment: I have just read about it briefly. Does it offer an way to log what records were upserted? Not sure if it has the ability to update the parent record when the child is being updated. Any idea?

Comment: S2S allows for triggers to be written when S2S event happens so yes, lookup record could be updated;

Comment: @cropredy In my case I have an external id on XYZ object. This external id reference to the parent of XYZ object. I will be publishing only the XYZ object using S2S. Will it update the parent of XYZ automatically or do I have to write a trigger for this.

Comment: you will need in S2S to pass as fields in XYZ everything needed by remote S2S system's trigger on XYZ to CRUD the lookup field

Comment: @cropredy Thanks. I am going to send the external Id field on XYZ object from one instance to another. Are you saying I have to write a trigger and query the parent object and run an update on it?

Comment: @cropredy Does S2S integration does not allow mapping lookup fields on an object? I tried this approach between two developer orgs and I do not see an option to map the lookup field for the subscribed object. Any idea?

Comment: @sfdcfox Does S2S integration does not allow mapping lookup fields on an object? I tried this approach between two developer orgs and I do not see an option to map the lookup field for the subscribed object. Any idea?

Comment: You misunderstood me, for object XYZ, include as formula/hidden fields everything you need to reconstruct the lookup parent on the target org